# Angular: Looping and displaying all the value starting from specific $index in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've come across many similar question but not yet came across to exactly how I want this to work. Here's a plunker which is not my work, I've just amended it:
http://plnkr.co/edit/ntlZjxnV6we9Je2OZnLL?p=preview

You can see that there are list of days in a week in data.json file. I've managed to display the days from `tue` for tuesday however, it does not display the other days which are before the `tue` index which are `sun` and `mon` which should show under `sat`. Is there a way to display rest of the days before `tue` index?

Comment: I don't understand what is your goal. Which days you want to be printed?

Comment: Goal is to print sun and mon also under sat :)

Comment: Like that, all the days will be printed, if for example I printed the days starting from wed $index, then sun, mon and tue should be printed under sat. Hope it makes sense now.

Comment: Maybe this solution acceptable for you http://plnkr.co/edit/R2vemKHKow0dJKqORcOC?p=preview

Comment: That's a really good solution @YuriyP, thanks a lot. Isn't there any possibility to concat in ng-repeat?

Comment: If you really want to perform it in html you can do it in next way http://plnkr.co/edit/bO2oBjbEJEqtoRFEYsY6?p=preview

Comment: @YuriyP Wow, thanks a lot. You deserve the best answer as I wanted this to perform only in html

Answer (score 2):

Ok i think i understand what you want. [Here is a working solution](http://plnkr.co/edit/pSlBJpfM647Hkt47JL9a).

The function `listElementsAfterIndex` gets a collection, and the index to split the collection.

**Controller**

```
$scope.name = data.name;
    $scope.children = data.children;


    $scope.listElementsAfterIndex = function(collection, index) {

      var head = collection.slice(0, index + 1);
      var tail = collection.slice(index + 1);
      return tail.concat(head);

    }
```

**View**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <h2>Days</h2>

  <div ng-repeat="child in listElementsAfterIndex(children,1)">
    {{child.data}}
  </div>
  <br> ^ Displaying rest of the days here now under `sat` which are `sun` and `mon`
</body>
```

Comment: Brilliant, works as I wanted, thanks a lot :) 

Isn't there a way to do this concatenation in ng-repeat in the html?